# How to have a sql parameter regex in SQL data command string

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to pass a `SqlParameter` to a SQL Server query which passes the parameter into a regular expression. My issue is that the SQL Server is taking '%@str%' literally (`@str` is the parameter) and I don't know what to do to get passed this.

I've looked at using the Regex library, but I don't want to get an output and filter the output with a regular expression, I just want a regular expression to directly influence the result in the output from the server.

In case I've managed to mess up my explanation on how the query works, here is the faulty data command string:

```
"SELECT Customer.LastName ... 
 FROM Customer 
 WHERE Customer.LastName Like '%@str%' 
 ORDER BY Customer.LastName;"
```

Comment: Change it to `LIKE '%' + @str + '%'`? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Sql server does not support regular expressions. I think you are looking for `Customer.LastName Like '%'+ @str +'%'`

Comment: Alright that worked, thanks. Can you explain why the change you made works though?

Comment: Because `@str` isn't evaluated as a literal string if it's outside quotation marks. If you put `@str` in quotation marks, SQL just assumes you want to literally search for the string `'@str'`.

Comment: No I mean '%'+ and then the space. What does that tell the SQL server to do?

Comment: I mean I know that it somehow gets @str doesn't get str to be recognized as literal, but why the quotes on either side of the ampersand and then a space? Like what do the characters represent is what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: What does "Like '%' + @str + '%'" do?... That's easy, it prevents the use of an index, causing a scan of the Customer table, resulting in poor performance. You should avoid the use of leading wildcards whenever possible.

Comment: That's just to convert the whole statement to a search string with any number of wild characters. If the value of `@str` was `'test'`, then `LIKE '%' + @str + '%'` will match with `'%test%'` which in SQL means any string that contains the substring `test`. `%` is a wild card character that can match any number of characters in a string. `+` is just for concatenation of the strings together - it starts the string with %, then concatenates the value of @str and then concatenates % again at the end.